# Отображение модального окна в телефоне. Убрать клавиатуру

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Есть функция которая при фокусе, или клике на поле инпут, вызывает функцию которая вызывает собсвенно модальное окно. Все работает хорошо. Но, если я к примеру, вызываю модальное окно (при фокусировке, клике) в телефоне, то, мне вылетает клавиатура для ввода текста, а за ним виднеется то модальное окно.. которое было вызванно при клике на input поле.

Вопрос заключается в том, можно ли как то заблокировать вызов клавиатуры ? Что бы при фокусе, или клике, она не вызывалась (если мы вызываем функцию для отображение модального окна)

Comment: Можно развечто подавлять фокус, если произошёл клик, "случайный" или одиночный, возможно первый клик. При установке фокуса большинство браузеров сами показывают клавиатуру. Или сложнее - емулировать окно ввода div-ом, а когда нужно ставить нормальный Input.

Comment: Нет, у меня логика такова. Есть форма, в ней есть селект, его нужно выбрать первым.Т.е если юзер нажимает на любое текстовое поле, срабатывает функция проверки селекта, а потом функция вывода модального окна (в случае если селект не выбран). Это все работает на десктопах без проблем. Единсвенно что мне не нравиться, что на мобильном, при нажатии на текстовое поле, вылетает модальное окно, а потом и сама клавиатура.. Проблема в том что как спрятать это клавиатуру, или каким способом сделать те же действие что бы клавиатура не появлялась ?

Comment: Делаете проверку, если проверка не прошла - устанавливаете фокус на селекте назад. События onfocus onblur. Скрипту не запрещено перебивать фокус. А если правильно то пусть вводят дальше.

Comment: Дело в том что у меня функция обхватывает все элементы в форме с текстовыми полями. Вот собсвенно код `function Checksel() {
if ($("#select_category").val() === "") {
$('#myModal').modal();
}
}


$(".formpost").on("focusin", "input[type='text'],textarea", function() { 
Checksel();
});` т.е я работаю с формой из функции, не трогая и не модифицируя сами поля в форме. Возможно то что я хочу сделать из данного кода добавивь нужные функции ?

Comment: Эм нашел решение, но думаю как его применить,  перед вызовом модального окна, ставим инпутам readonly true, тогда кейбор де вылазит, но вот теперь нужно понять на какое событие его ставить. Ибо по клику вылазит, а когда нажимаю второй раз, то все ок. Просто запутался в этих фокусах блурах )

Comment: А, понял что вы имели виду делать проверку, нет такой вариант не подойдет ! Цель в том что бы юзер сначала выбрал в селекте категорию, и только потом заполнял все остальные поля. Ибо если он начнет заполнять сначала все поля, а потом выберит категорию, то, все поля сбросятся ! Такая уж технология. Вот и ищю выход, но я его нашел, осталось только с ФОКУСОМ разабраться, почему нельзя никак опередить это клавиатуру...